# Shared Element transition animation issue

Tags: android, android-transitions

I have a `LoginActivity` which consist of two buttons **Login** and **Register**. I am trying to share the **Register** button from `LoginActivity` to `RegistrationActivity`. The transition animation is happening but the animation is not coming smoothly. The problem is **Register** button is taking whole height and width of the `LoginActivity` before moving to the `RegistrationActivity`.

Here is the screenshot of the problem. You can see the **Register** button taking whole height and width of the layout:
[image]

My `LoginActivity` code where I am jumping to `ResgitrationActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(LoginActivity.this, register, "register");
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

in my `onPause()` of both `LoginActivity` and `RegistrationActivity` I am calling this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
```

Here is my `style.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#3b5998</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RegistrationButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#F44E3F</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextLabel" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#FFF</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#FFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My `LoginActivity` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ignite.a01hw909350.kolamdemo.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_img" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_img" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_user"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_password"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginSubmit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"
            android:textColor="#fff" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerText"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:theme="@style/RegistrationButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my `RegistrationActivity` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/registerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_morning_background"
    tools:context="com.ignite.a01hw909350.kolamdemo.RegistrationActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:alpha="0.37"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_img" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:alpha="0.37"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_img" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/registerContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/regUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e6f3f0"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/regNickname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e6f3f0"
            android:hint="@string/nickname"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/regEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e6f3f0"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/regPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e6f3f0"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/regDOB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e6f3f0"
            android:hint="@string/dob"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/regTOB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e6f3f0"
            android:hint="@string/tob"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lang"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:prompt="@string/language" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/regPOB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#e6f3f0"
            android:hint="@string/pob"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regSubmit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:theme="@style/RegistrationButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/registerContentLayout"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am testing this on a Marshmallow powered Android device. **Why the animation is not smooth?**

Comment: Can you share a `gif`?

Comment: updated with gif @azizbekian

Comment: Can you post also `styles.xml` and layout files of each activity? Better post a simple project with that behavior on github.

Comment: @azizbekian updated the question. You can even see there is even a delay while starting activity

Comment: Before trying to provide any answer or hint, it would be helpfull both for you and for SO that you set device developer options such as to 1)slow down animation and transitions and 2)turn on drawing bounding boxes